# addAttr method on pymel objects

Tags: python, methods, maya, pymel

I can't seem to utilize the addAttr method correctly. I'm using the same arguments as when I call from pymel.core but it's not giving me the same results.

I'm trying to add a custom message attribute so I can easily search for certain types of objects later. When I do it from pymel.core and include the same object reference as an argument, it works fine.

```
#get object reference
test_object = pm.ls(sl=1)[0]

#this one spits out an error
test_object.addAttr(longName = 'custom', attributeType = 'message')

#this one works fine
pm.addAttr(test_object, longName = 'custom', attributeType = 'message')
```

I keep getting this error
Error: TypeError: file  line 1: addAttr() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
What additional argument is it looking for when I use it this way? I am clearly missing something obvious about how methods work but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The addAttr method exposed for DG nodes in Maya PyMel has following signature.

```
addAttr(attr, **kwargs)
```

Here `attr` is an positional argument representing the attribute name. The kwargs can be supplied with all other relevant flags used in `pm.addAttr()` method. So you have to pass the attribute name as first argument.

```
node.addAttr('custom', attributeType='message')
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thank you, that summed it up very nicely for me.

Answer (score 0):

from [cgsociety](https://forums.cgsociety.org/t/most-bulletproof-and-safe-way-of-adding-custom-attributes/1603871/2) thread

```
pCube.addAttr('timeBasedAttr', keyable=True, attributeType='float', min=0.0, max=1.0)
```

you should write :

```
test_object.addAttr('custom', attributeType = 'message')
```

Ive tried and it doesn't output error.

Comment: Oh weird, I guess it's just the way I was assigning the name. Thanks!